# Error when getting go package from github

Tags: go

I get the below error when doing a `go get` on one of the github packages

```
bash-3.2$ go get -d github.com/percona/percona-backup-mongodb
package github.com/percona/percona-backup-mongodb: no Go files in /Users/sanupin/go-workspace/src/github.com/percona/percona-backup-mongodb
```

I understand there is no `main()` in the top level directory, but how do I fix this?

```
bash-3.2$ go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/Users/sanupin/go-workspace/bin"
GOCACHE="/Users/sanupin/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/sanupin/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/sanupin/go-workspace/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/sanupin/go-workspace"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/sr/n5q9l_fn7yj8mx6rbfq8smbn72mpx6/T/go-build148246931=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Comment: can you try go get -d github.com/percona/percona-backup-mongodb/...

Comment: show `go env`, please

Comment: @kozmo I just edited post to have the go env details

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Isn't that what I already did?

`bash-3.2$  go get -d github.com/percona/percona-backup-mongodb/
package github.com/percona/percona-backup-mongodb: no Go files in /Users/sanupin/go-workspace/src/github.com/percona/percona-backup-mongodb`

Comment: no in the end add "/..."

Answer (score 4):

You tell `go get` the name of a package. A directory with no go files isn't a package. So run `go get` on the package you actually want to use, e.g `github.com/percona/percona-backup-mongodb/agent` or `github.com/percona/percona-backup-mongodb/cmd`.